# Mouse clicks aren't recognized by pygame Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Before I start, I'm going to apologize in advance for this terrible code. I'm just starting out and I am trying to create a Tic-Tac-Toe game with pygame because I felt that it would be some good practice. The problem I'm having is that a lot of my mouse clicks aren't being picked up and I have to click many times for it to work and also at the end of the game the program goes unresponsive. I've searched around the internet but have found no solution.
I'm using python 3.6 on windows 10.

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

display_width = 600
display_height = 600

black = (0, 0, 0)
light_grey = (180, 180, 180)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
light_blue = (0, 137, 255)

game_background = pygame.image.load("Tic-tac-toe.png")

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

pygame.display.set_caption('Tic Tac Toe')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

my_big_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 64)
my_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
my_small_font = pygame.font.Font('Calibri-Light.ttf', 20)

begin_text = my_font.render('Would you like to begin?', 1, black)
yes_text = my_font.render('YES', 1, black)
no_text = my_font.render('NO', 1, black)
instructions_title = my_font.render('INSTRUCTIONS', 1, black)
instructions_start = my_font.render('START', 1, black)
instructions_body1 = my_small_font.render('The object of Tic Tac Toe is to', 1, black)
instructions_body2 = my_small_font.render('get  three  in  a  row.  Players', 1, black)
instructions_body3 = my_small_font.render('alternate  placing  Xs  and  Os', 1, black)
instructions_body4 = my_small_font.render('on   the   game   board   until', 1, black)
instructions_body5 = my_small_font.render('either  opponent   has   three', 1, black)
instructions_body6 = my_small_font.render('in  a  row  or all  nine squares', 1, black)
instructions_body7 = my_small_font.render('are    filled.   In     the   event', 1, black)
instructions_body8 = my_small_font.render('that    no   one    has    three', 1, black)
instructions_body9 = my_small_font.render('in  a  row,  the  game  results', 1, black)
instructions_body0 = my_small_font.render('in  a  tie.', 1, black)

global ready
global instructions

done = False
ready = False
instructions = False
start = True

yes_position = pygame.Rect(175, 275, 100, 50)
no_position = pygame.Rect(325, 275, 100, 50)
start_position = pygame.Rect(202, 452, 198, 48)
position0 = pygame.Rect(25, 25, 150, 150)
position1 = pygame.Rect(226, 25, 150, 150)
position2 = pygame.Rect(420, 25, 150, 150)
position3 = pygame.Rect(25, 230, 150, 150)
position4 = pygame.Rect(226, 230, 150, 150)
position5 = pygame.Rect(420, 230, 150, 150)
position6 = pygame.Rect(25, 430, 150, 150)
position7 = pygame.Rect(226, 430, 150, 150)
position8 = pygame.Rect(420, 425, 150, 150)

print(my_big_font.size('YOU LOSE!!!'))


def quitting():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        quit()

def draw_start():
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [150, 200, 300, 150], 1)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, light_grey, [151, 201, 298, 148])
    gameDisplay.blit(begin_text, (175, 225))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, [175, 275, 100, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [174, 274, 102, 52], 3)
    gameDisplay.blit(yes_text, (203, 289))
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [325, 275, 100, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [324, 274, 102, 52], 3)
    gameDisplay.blit(no_text, (359, 289))

def draw_instructions_body():
    gameDisplay.blit(instructions_body1, (180, 160))
    gameDisplay.blit(instructions_body2, (180, 185))
    gameDisplay.blit(instructions_body3, (180, 210))
    gameDisplay.blit(instructions_body4, (180, 235))
    gameDisplay.blit(instructions_body5, (180, 260))
    gameDisplay.blit(instructions_body6, (180, 285))
    gameDisplay.blit(instructions_body7, (180, 310))
    gameDisplay.blit(instructions_body8, (180, 335))
    gameDisplay.blit(instructions_body9, (180, 360))
    gameDisplay.blit(instructions_body0, (180, 385))

def draw_instructions():
    if instructions:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [150, 100, 300, 425], 1)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, light_grey, [151, 101, 298, 423])
        gameDisplay.blit(instructions_title, (214, 115))
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, [202, 452, 198, 48])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [200, 450, 200, 50], 2)
        gameDisplay.blit(instructions_start, (264, 464))
        draw_instructions_body()
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [165, 150, 270, 265], 1)

def draw_x(x, y):
    pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, [x, y], [(x + 100), (y + 100)], 20)
    pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, [(x + 100), y], [x, (y + 100)], 20)

def draw_o(x, y):
    pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, black, [x + 60, y + 60], 60)
    pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, white, [x + 60, y + 60], 45)



def start():
    global ready
    global instructions
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        if event.button == 1:
            if yes_position.collidepoint(event.pos):
                pygame.time.delay(100)
                instructions = True

            if start_position.collidepoint(event.pos) and instructions:
                instructions = False
                gameDisplay.fill(white)
                gameDisplay.blit(game_background, (0, 0))
                pygame.display.update()
                ready = True

            if no_position.collidepoint(event.pos):
                pygame.time.delay(500)
                pygame.quit()
                quit()



def drawplayerpiece(a, b):
    if player_piece == 'x':
        draw_x(a, b)
    if player_piece == 'o':
        draw_o(a, b)

global game_start
global order
global game_board
game_start = False
order = 0

game_board = [' '] * 9

def draw_new_board():
    global game_board
    if game_board[0] == 'o':
        draw_o(25, 25)
    if game_board[1] == 'o':
        draw_o(226, 25)
    if game_board[2] == 'o':
        draw_o(420, 25)
    if game_board[3] == 'o':
        draw_o(25, 230)
    if game_board[4] == 'o':
        draw_o(226, 230)
    if game_board[5] == 'o':
        draw_o(420, 230)
    if game_board[6] == 'o':
        draw_o(25, 430)
    if game_board[7] == 'o':
        draw_o(226, 430)
    if game_board[8] == 'o':
        draw_o(420, 425)
    if game_board[0] == 'x':
        draw_x(25, 25)
    if game_board[1] == 'x':
        draw_x(226, 25)
    if game_board[2] == 'x':
        draw_x(420, 25)
    if game_board[3] == 'x':
        draw_x(25, 230)
    if game_board[4] == 'x':
        draw_x(226, 230)
    if game_board[5] == 'x':
        draw_x(420, 230)
    if game_board[6] == 'x':
        draw_x(25, 430)
    if game_board[7] == 'x':
        draw_x(226, 430)
    if game_board[8] == 'x':
        draw_x(420, 425)

# 0  1  2
# 3  4  5
# 6  7  8

def draw_win(x, y, a, b, p):
    if p == player_piece:
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, green, [x, y], [a, b], 20)
        pygame.time.delay(200)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, [150, 200, 300, 150],)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [150, 200, 300, 150], 2)
        gameDisplay.blit((my_big_font.render('YOU WIN!!!', 1, black)), (180, 250))
        pygame.time.delay(2000)

    if p == computer_piece:
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, red, [x, y], [a, b], 20)
        pygame.time.delay(200)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [150, 200, 300, 150],)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [150, 200, 300, 150], 2)
        gameDisplay.blit((my_big_font.render('YOU LOSE!!!', 1, black)), (160, 250))
        pygame.time.delay(2000)

def checkwin(x):
    if (game_board[0] == x and game_board[1] == x and game_board[2] == x):
        draw_win(50, 100, 550, 100, x)
    if (game_board[3] == x and game_board[4] == x and game_board[5] == x):
        draw_win(50, 300, 550, 300, x)
    if (game_board[6] == x and game_board[7] == x and game_board[8] == x):
        draw_win(50, 500, 550, 500, x)
    if (game_board[0] == x and game_board[3] == x and game_board[6] == x):
        draw_win(100, 50, 100, 550, x)
    if (game_board[1] == x and game_board[4] == x and game_board[7] == x):
        draw_win(300, 50, 300, 550, x)
    if (game_board[2] == x and game_board[5] == x and game_board[8] == x):
        draw_win(500, 50, 500, 550, x)
    if (game_board[0] == x and game_board[4] == x and game_board[8] == x):
        draw_win(75, 75, 525, 525, x)
    if (game_board[6] == x and game_board[4] == x and game_board[2] == x):
        draw_win(75, 525, 525, 75, x)

def checkdraw():
    if not checkwin() and ' ' not in game_board:
        return True        


def game_loop():
    global order
    global game_start
    global player_piece
    global computer_piece
    global game_board
    if not game_start:
        game_board = [' '] * 9
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, light_grey, [200, 250, 200, 100])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [200, 250, 200, 100], 1)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, light_blue, [235, 300, 45, 35])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [235, 300, 45, 35], 1)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, light_blue, [320, 300, 45, 35])
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [320, 300, 45, 35], 1)
        gameDisplay.blit((my_font.render('X', 1, black)), (250, 307))
        gameDisplay.blit((my_font.render('O', 1, black)), (334, 307))
        gameDisplay.blit((my_small_font.render('What do you want', 1, black)), (225, 256))
        gameDisplay.blit((my_small_font.render('to play as?', 1, black)), (255, 275))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    if (pygame.Rect(235, 300, 45, 35)).collidepoint(event.pos):
                        player_piece = 'x'
                        computer_piece = 'o'
                        order = 2
                        game_start = True
                    if (pygame.Rect(320, 300, 45, 35)).collidepoint(event.pos):
                        player_piece = 'o'
                        computer_piece = 'x'
                        order = 1
                        game_start = True
    if game_start:
        if order == 1:
            computer_move()
            checkwin((computer_piece))
            order = 2
        if order == 2:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    if event.button == 1:
                        if position0.collidepoint(event.pos) and game_board[0] == ' ':
                            game_board[0] = player_piece
                            drawplayerpiece(25, 25)
                            checkwin((player_piece))
                            order = 1
                        if position1.collidepoint(event.pos) and game_board[1] == ' ':
                            drawplayerpiece(226, 25)
                            game_board[1] = player_piece
                            checkwin((player_piece))
                            order = 1
                        if position2.collidepoint(event.pos) and game_board[2] == ' ':
                            drawplayerpiece(420, 25)
                            game_board[2] = player_piece
                            checkwin((player_piece))
                            order = 1
                        if position3.collidepoint(event.pos) and game_board[3] == ' ':
                            drawplayerpiece(25, 230)
                            game_board[3] = player_piece
                            checkwin((player_piece))
                            order = 1
                        if position4.collidepoint(event.pos) and game_board[4] == ' ':
                            drawplayerpiece(226, 230)
                            game_board[4] = player_piece
                            checkwin((player_piece))
                            order = 1
                        if position5.collidepoint(event.pos) and game_board[5] == ' ':
                            drawplayerpiece(420, 230)
                            game_board[5] = player_piece
                            checkwin((player_piece))
                            order = 1
                        if position6.collidepoint(event.pos) and game_board[6] == ' ':
                            drawplayerpiece(25, 430)
                            game_board[6] = player_piece
                            checkwin((player_piece))
                            order = 1
                        if position7.collidepoint(event.pos) and game_board[7] == ' ':
                            drawplayerpiece(226, 430)
                            game_board[7] = player_piece
                            checkwin((player_piece))
                            order = 1
                        if position8.collidepoint(event.pos) and game_board[8] == ' ':
                            drawplayerpiece(420, 425)
                            game_board[8] = player_piece
                            checkwin((player_piece))
                            order = 1                            
        draw_new_board()
        checkwin('x')
        checkwin('o')

global computer_test_location
computer_test_location = 100

def computer_move():
    global computer_test_location
    global game_board
    global computer_piece
    computer_test_location = random.randint(0, 8)
    pygame.time.delay(500)
    while True:
        if game_board[(computer_test_location)] == ' ':
            game_board[(computer_test_location)] = computer_piece
            break
        computer_test_location = random.randint(0, 8)


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        quitting()
        if not ready:
            start()

    if not ready:
        if start:
            draw_start()
        if instructions:
            draw_instructions()
    if ready:
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        gameDisplay.blit(game_background, (0, 0))
        game_loop()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You have a LOT of code. In the future please try to only post the parts you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have several event loops that are executed consecutively. That means the first `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop will have emptied the queue when you enter the `game_loop` and you see only events that are added in the short time between the first event loop and the second event loop.

A quick fix would be to assign the events to a variable in the outer event loop (`pygame.event.get` returns a list), use this list in the first event loop and then pass it to the `game_loop` function where you can iterate over it a second time.

```
events = pygame.event.get()
for event in events:
    # ...

if ready:
    game_loop(events)
```

In the `game_loop` function:

```
def game_loop(events):
    # ...
    for event in events:
```

Comment: If you want more suggestions or refactoring tips, visit https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pygame